# Why is datepicker ui one week behind php date("W")

Tags: php, jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker

I'm working with php and datepicker for an application that requires the week number from a date. I just noticed that datepicker is one week behind php date("W"). I have a [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/progrower/Lckh46up/) showing the issue. Is there a way to correct this? Thanks for any insight.

JS:

```
 <script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $( ".datepicker" ).datepicker({
           showWeek: true,
           dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd' 
         });
    });
 </script>
```

PHP:

```
<?php echo 'Current week ' .date("W");?>
```

HTML:

```
<input name="date_task[]" class="datepicker" type="text"  />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix it by changing the first day of the week to monday.

```
 <script>
   $(document).ready(function () {
     $( ".datepicker" ).datepicker({
              showWeek: true,
              dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd', 
              firstDay: 1
         });
     });
 </script>
```